# Mechanical keyboard with a laptop-like layout

Tags: keyboards

Are there any mechanical keyboards with laptop-like layout for reasonable price(below 80$ is ok, below 60$ is good, below 40$ is great)? What I mean is something like this or at least almost similar:

[image: Keyboard]

Bottom left row has 4 keys - ctrl, fn, win, alt; arrow keys also serve as Pg up, Pg down, Home, End;

Cheaper is better and I don't mind changing caps or resoldering switches, if needed.

DIY PCB recommendations are also welcome.

Comment: You'll need to be more quantitative with "reasonable price". Only you know what's most reasonable for you ;) .

Comment: I would say either as cheap as possible - so that I can reassemble it with different switches and microcontroller, as I am alright with soldering and programming. Or somewhat below 80-60$, as mechanical keyboards that I would consider "ok" as in usage feeling can be had for about that price. And I have also been offered to buy a 36$ mechanical keyboard for half of the price from someone who decided to get rid of it.

Comment: I can only really offer consumer grade mechanical keyboard recommendations as DIY type kits are out of my knowledge area. If your friend is offering you a mechanical keyboard for half price and you're happy with it that's probably a pretty quick open and shut deal. I can double-check if the price you're getting for the keyboard is good if you tell me it's make and model,.

Comment: The only issue I see is the arrow keys. Since mechanical keyboards require large switches, there's not really a good way to get those little keys the same way you can with a membrane keyboard. This is the case with 60% keyboards like the [POK3R](https://mechanicalkeyboards.com/shop/index.php?l=product_list&c=165). Also, any custom keyboard is going to be >$80, likely well into $175+ range, even with you assembling it yourself. The $36 for the keyboard, assuming Cherry/Omeron switches, is a pretty great deal. If you can live with whatever compromises that keyboard makes, I'd recommend it.